# Select row with the highest order value

Tags: sql, oracle11g, greatest-n-per-group

For example, I have the table with the next columns: id, fk_id, date, order. How can I select something like this:

```
select 
  id
from cards
where fk_id = pId
and date = pDate;
```

but I need to get only the row with the highest order value. How can I do that? Thank you.

UPD1: First of all - thank you for your answers. Column names are completely different in the real table, it's just dummy names for question. Is there any way to do so that select by joining tha table with itself?

Answer (score 3):

You would use the aggregating function KEEP DENSE_RANK FIRST for that:

```
select 
MIN(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY "order" desc) 
from cards
where fk_id = pId
and "date" = pDate;
```

Comment: I've just edited my answer and put the column names order and date in quotes to make Oracle see it as a column name rather than a key word. You should not name columns with key words.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
SELECT id
FROM cards
WHERE orderValue = (SELCT MAX(orderValue)
                    FROM cards
                    WHERE fk_id = pId
                    AND date = pDate)
AND fk_id = pId
AND date = pDate;
```

This is fairly efficient.

Comment: This gives you any records with that order value. You would have to limit results to pID and pDate again to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
select 
id
from cards
where fk_id = pId
and date = pDate 
order by desc 
limit 1;
```

Comment: @Ben - Did not see the tag Oracle :). It works in MYSQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, do not use the words "order" and "date" for column names. Both are reserved words in SQL (ORDER BY ... clause, DATE is a data type). So in my example I am going to use "myorder" and "mydate" instead...

I assume your example as purely hypothetical because with the selected column names it would most likely not work on any SQL database, anyway.

In Oracle database you could try this:

```
select ID from 
( select ID, row_number() over (partition by ID order by MYORDER) as RN
  from CARDS where FK_ID = PID and MYDATE = PDATE)
where RN = 1
```

However, your select only has one column, ID. So if you simply do

```
select distinct ID from CARDS
```

you will get exactly the same result...